# A amazing result with CUDA GPU when block number is large

Tags: cuda, gpu, block

Recently I work with CUDA programming, I met an incredible problem when the blockNum Exceeding 500. In order to simplify the mode,I wrote the following test code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>  
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
/* Example from "Introduction to CUDA C" from NVIDIA website:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-education

Compile with:
$ nvcc example_intro.cu */

#define num 1000
const int N = num*32*12;

__global__ void add_blocks (int *a,  int *c) {
   int threadId = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * blockDim.y 
                + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int block_id = threadIdx.y;
    if(threadId % 2 == 0){
        c[threadId] =  1;
    }
}


int main(void) {

    int *a, *c; 
    int *d_a,  *d_c; /* Device (GPU) copies of a, b, c */
    size_t size = N * sizeof(int);

    /* Allocate memory in device */
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_c, size);

    /* Allocate memory in host */
    a = (int *) malloc(size);
    c = (int *) malloc(size);

    /* Allocate random data in vectors a and b (inside host) */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        a[i] = 0;
        c[i] = 0;
    }

    /* Copy data to device */
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 threads_per_block(32, 12);
    add_blocks<<<num, threads_per_block>>>(d_a,d_c);
    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaError_t errSync  = cudaGetLastError();
    if (errSync != cudaSuccess) 
    printf("Sync kernel error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(errSync));

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if(c[i] == 1){
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",counter);

    /* Clean-up */
    free(a); 
    free(c);
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_c);

    return 0;
  }
```

when the thread num is multiples of 2, I set the c array with 1, and in the end I count the num of 1, which I think is  N/2. It works well when block num is below 500, for example is num*32*12/2 = 500 * 32 * 12 / 2 = 96 000. But when num is 1000 the result is 312846 which should be 192000. Anyone can help me? thanks all.

Comment: I am sure that *somtimes* it doesn't "work well when block num is below 500" . The problem as nothing to do with the number of block you run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    if(c[i] == 1){
        counter ++;
    }
}
printf("%d\n",counter);
```

You are implicitly assuming that every value of 1 in `c` must have been set by the prior GPU kernel. However, you never set the value of half of the elements in `d_c` (and thus `c` at this point in the program) at all, so there is no guarantee that some of those also won't have a value of 1. Reading and using the values of unitialized memory isn't amazing, it is just bad programming practice.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I realized the bug yesterday,  but it's too late to test it, I just gone to sleep. Away, thanks you a lot, I will pay a attention this kind of bugs.